# Regex to grab everything before a pattern that may or may not appear

Tags: regex

I've been trying to come up with a regex that will match on everything, except for the following pattern and everything after it:

```
elasped:\s*\d+
```

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
.+ [\w\.\)\-]*[\:\D]*(?<! elapsed:)
```

Been playing with the pattern and example text at the following [URL](http://regex101.com/r/fX7wU9/1)

However, I haven't been able to get it to grab everything in the example log lines that I provide at that URL.

Comment: Something [like this](http://regex101.com/r/fX7wU9/3)?

Comment: Would that be the same as if line.IndexOf("elapsed") > -1 then truncate the line?

Comment: Or something [like that](http://regex101.com/r/fX7wU9/5)? Please specify, if it is for each line or a multiline input total.

Comment: @Jonny5 I like your first regex, but it'd be easy as well just to remove `elapsed: ` part in that case. As for the second one, it's easier to get with plain lookahead (but without global flag), I think.

Comment: Still, I don't think it's a good question. First, it's hard to understand what exactly the OP wants (both cases @Jonny5 mentioned are equally possible). Second, it's plain wrong to ask regex-related question without specifying the target language as well. I won't downvote the question, because the effort was applied by the OP; still I vote for its closing (as it's unclear).

Comment: For me it's unclear, what exactly trying to achieve. Some sample input and expected output would be great.

Comment: @raina77ow yes of course you're right, just forgot to remove the global flag, was trying around. Also it should be equivalent to [something like this](http://regex101.com/r/fX7wU9/6) which is possibly more efficient using a lookahead like you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, this is for parsing log files in Splunk... so I want to evaluate each line individually.  @Jonny5 first link appears to be what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Just use lookahead:

```
.*?(?= elapsed:\d+)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://regex101.com/r/nU9yS8/1). The regex will stop matching right before the first occurrence of `elapsed:` in the tried string.